# Sort Embedded Documents in Array and fetch specifics

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoose model like this:

```
var activityItem = mongoose.Schema({
    timestampValue: Number,
    xabc: String,
    full: Boolean,
    comp: Boolean
});

var ABC = mongoose.Schema({
    activity: [activityItem],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    username: String
});
```

I want to get the activityItem array elements that have a `timestampValue` less than a specific value. Also, I want to sort the `activity` array first according to the `timestampValue`

This is the code that I currently have. And it doesn't work.

```
UserActivity.findOne({
    'user': current_user,
    'activity' : {
        $all: [
            {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    timestampValue: {
                        $lte: time
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},

function(err, user){

})
```

Sample Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7c6"),
    "user" : ObjectId("56bf225342e662f4277ded73"),
    "notifications" : [],
    "completed" : [],
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "timestampValue": 1456902600000,
            "xabc": "Some value",
            "full": true,
            "comp": false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7d2")
        }, 
        {
            "timestampValue": 1456702600000,
            "xabc": "Some other value",
            "full": true,
            "comp": false,
            "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7d3")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

The POST call has the following params

```
hash: "2e74aaaf42aa5ea733be963cb61fc5ff"
time: 1457202600000
```

`hash` comes into the picture once i have the docs from mongo
`time` is a unix timestamp value.

Instead of returning only the elements that are less than the `time` value, it is returning all the array elements. I tried the aggregation framework to sort the array before querying, but couldn't get the hang of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample input documents added to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to do it through `aggregation` as below

```
ABS.aggregate([
    // filter the document by current_user
    {$match: {user: ObjectId(current_user)}},
    // unwind the activity array
    {$unwind: '$activity'},
    // filter the timestampValue less than time
    {$match: {'activity.timestampValue': {$lte: time}}},
    // sort activity by timestampValue in ascending order
    {$sort: {'activity.timestampValue': 1}},
    // group by _id, and assemble the activity array.
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', user: {$first: '$user'},activity: {$push: '$activity'}}}
], function(err, results){
    if (err)
        throw err;

    // populate user to get details of user information if needed
    //ABS.populate( results, { "path": "user" }, function(err, rets) {
        //
    //});
});
```

Comment: this works well. but it doesn't query the user. How can I do this aggregation for a `current_user`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think maybe my question wasnt clear enough. Apologies for that. The activity array should be aggregated after I've selected a particular document according to the user field. Please take a look at the code example in the question. Thanks again :)

Comment: @amit, maybe I misunderstand you? However, in your fist comment, you mentioned it work well... it confused me...

Comment: @amit,  test with the sample data and my codes, the result I got is `{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dd7c0745d1c0a7f3c11634"), "user" : "123456", "activity" : [ { "timestampValue" : 20000, "full" : true, "comp" : false }, { "timestampValue" : 30000, "full" : true, "comp" : true } ] }`

Comment: it can pull out values from the activity array just fine. the thing is suppose there are multiple documents with different id's just like `ObjectId("56dd7c0745d1c0a7f3c11634")` with different unique `user` fields. I want to get the document first, and then search through the activity array of embedded documents.

Comment: I also tried to do this: `ABC.findOne({user: current_user }, function(err, abc){ abc.aggregate() })` but it didnt have the aggregate function.

Comment: @amit, Sorry for misunderstanding you. To filter the document by `current_user` could be done through `{$match: {user: current_user}}`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: if I remove the first `$match` that queries the user, I am able to get the results. i get an empty array if i include that query. anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105647/discussion-between-zangw-and-amit).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems little bit tricky with MongoDb aggregation pipeline unless you have MongoDB 3.2, but you can definitely 
achieve your result with help of map-reduce.

e.g.

> MongoDB version < 3.2

```
var findActivities = function (time) {
    db.col.mapReduce(function () {
        var item = Object.assign({}, this);
        delete item.activity;
        item.activity = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.activity.length; i++) {
            if (this.activity[i].timestampValue <= time) {
                item.activity.push(this.activity[i]);
            }
        }

        emit(item._id, item);
    }, function (k, v) {
        return {items: v};
    }, {
        out: {"inline": true},
        scope: {time: time}
    }).results.forEach(function (o) {
        printjson(o); // Or perform action as appropriate 
    });
};
```

Based your sample data when called `findActivities(1456802600000)`, it will find and return only those documents matching criteria.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7c6"), 
    "value" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7c6"), 
        "user" : ObjectId("56bf225342e662f4277ded73"), 
        "notifications" : [

        ], 
        "completed" : [

        ], 
        "__v" : NumberInt(1), 
        "activity" : [
            {
                "timestampValue" : NumberLong(1456702600000), 
                "xabc" : "Some other value", 
                "full" : true, 
                "comp" : false, 
                "_id" : ObjectId("56d5e88adfd14baf1848a7d3")
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

> MongoDB version 3.2+

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {$project:{user:1, notifications:1, completed:1, activity:{
      $filter:{input: "$activity", as: "activity", cond:{
        $lte: ["$$activity.timestampValue", 1456802600000]}}}}}
])
```

Both solutions will have same output.